# ReplaySubject: Only replay for a single IObservable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm trying to find a way to replay messages from a hot IObservable, but only do so for a single IObserver.  And do so using minimal memory.

If I use ReplaySubject, then I assume it keeps a copy of each item until the IObservable is disposed of.  I actually only want it to keep a copy of each item until the IObserver attaches itself.  After that point, it can act as if the ReplaySubject weren't even there.

Comment: If you want to prune which `IObserver`s receives values, I think you would need a custom implementation of `IObservable` (say, which takes into its ctor the criteria for which the `OnNext` will be called on an `IObserver`. For the latter problem, you can provide a `ReplaySubject` with a buffer size (i.e. how many to replay). These two seem like separate problems, though.

Comment: "I actually only want it to keep a copy of each item until the IObserver attaches itself. After that point, it can act as if the ReplaySubject weren't even there" - that's how `ReplaySubject` effectively works. You're just trying to reduce the memory? What is the type you're passing that has such a high memory footprint? What's the actual issue here?